# Load button on .hover() but dynamically for each child element

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML `<aside>` container and at this container I have `<div>` element which contains a `<span>` elements (which is my button)

I want to display a button only when I hover over the `<div>` element (name of the player), but dynamically for each player at my football players list

This was my try:

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3hnLs81q/4/

to make it dynamic. I thought I could use something like

```
$(aside).children(span)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve to the question itself, not a third party site. Also, be more specific about what "doesn't work".

Comment: Now thats a bummer. Your fiddle is working as you expect it to work. Just add jQuery to it. See your fiddle after adding jQuery:https://jsfiddle.net/3hnLs81q/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with pure CSS.

This CSS goes with your existing HTML.  Note the style at the bottom changing your child `<span>` element's visibility on hover.

```
.btnAddPlayer {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #4ad934;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.goalkeeper:hover span.btnAddPlayer {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3hnLs81q/5/

Comment: wow great :) Thanks! didnt know there are so much css possibilities out there...

Can i also do some like this too: 
.defender:hover ,.goalkeeper:hover span.btnAddPlayer{
  visibility: visible;
}

Comment: implement for more then one class a hover effect?

Comment: Yes you can!  That's a great thing to do actually if you know the styles should be the same!